# ¿Cómo puedo superponer un color semitransparente sobre toda la página en CSS? (Efecto filtro)

Tags: html, css

quiero dar un efecto como de filtro de color a toda la página que originalmente es blanco y negro. Podría poner un img o svg por encima de todos los elementos HTML y bajar la opacidad, pero quería saber si hay una manera mejor, más óptima y saber que estoy haciendo mal en mi código. He intentado tanto con z-index para poner el fondo de color por encima de la imagen de fondo pero no ha dado resultado.

**Código HTML:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código CSS:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Original:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Objetivo:**

[image: Objetivo:]

Comment: Pon el código _como texto, con formato_. [es.so] incluso te da las herramientas como para agregar un [repro] en la pregunta (teniendo en cuenta que es de html + css) a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). Lee [ask].

Comment: Con CSS prueba con filter y transition en el body. En [este enlace](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/filters/) tienes algunos ejemplos de su uso.

Comment: Un par de consejos. El primero, no vuelvas a mostrar tu código en imágenes. Es muy pesado para nosotros no poder copiar y pegar tu código para trabajar con él. En su lugar, escríbelo y formatéalo (selecciona el código escrito y pulsa Ctr+K) para poderlo usarlo nosotros también.

Comment: El segundo consejo es que compartas todo tu código si este no es muy grande. Veo que eres recién iniciado en este tema del desarrollo web. Muchas veces, sobre todo siendo principiante, pensamos que el fallo está en un lugar concreto y compartimos solo ese lugar concreto del código. Pero recuerda que estás empezando, luego tu capacidad crítica no es muy buena aún. Trata de pasar entonces todo el código y, si es muy largo, trata de replicar el problema en un "código de prueba" más pequeño para que los entendidos puedan estudiar bien el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para añadir el efecto que buscas(creo que esto es lo que quieres), por ejemplo sobre el bloque de clase home, prueba con el siguiente código:

```
.home::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: /*Aquí tendrás que buscar el color quieres en formato rgba, y recuerda que el último parámetro es la opacidad*/;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Lo que estamos haciendo con este código (el cual es responsive) es añadir un bloque sobre .home (para más detalles, busca after y before en Internet) y posicionarlo en el centro. Es importante la sentencia content=""; para que el bloque tenga contenido, pues, de lo contrario, no existiría el bloque al ser un bloque vacío sin medidas especificadas (técnicamente existiría, pero sería infinitamente pequeño y no lo veríamos).

Te muestro un ejemplo propio:

Antes

[image: imgAntes]

Después

[image: ImgDespues]

Puedo jugar con el color y la transparencia del nuevo bloque para ajustar el efecto a cómo quiero que se vea.

Cualquier cosa, pregunta.